# Select bookmarked lines in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, bookmarks, selection

is there any option ( plugin?) in Notepad++ to select all bookmarked lines?

I have enabled Multi-Editing settings this way: Settings -> Preferences -> Editing -> Multi-Editing Settings -> Enable

Greetings,
Mike

Comment: There does not appear to be a pre-built option in Notepad++. You can use Search > Bookmark to view a list of options such as Copy Bookmarked Lines. This may help to some degree depending on your purpose.

Comment: I know this option :) but what I need is selection, for example If You want to do some changes in selection range? Copy/modify is bad idea because it breaks document order and I can't merge it again ( at least it won't be easy ).

Comment: That makes sense. I was looking for through the plugins and didn't see anything that I thought would relate. I'm sorry I couldn't be more help on the matter.